# Is there an AmazonS3 connector available for ManifoldCF?

Tags: solr, amazon-s3, opensearch, manifoldcf

I would like to crawl an amazon s3 bucket using manifold to relay the crawl to OpenSearchServer. I've seen other products carry an amazon S3 connector and I'm just wondering if there is a publicly available one for ManifoldCF.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since Aug 27 there is one https://github.com/apache/manifoldcf/tree/trunk/connectors/amazons3

happy hacking!

Answer (score 1):

Currently manifold does not provide the Amazon S3 connector by default, [available connectors by default](https://manifoldcf.apache.org/release/release-1.9/en_US/end-user-documentation.html#repositoryconnectiontypes).

[How to write connectors](http://manifoldcf.apache.org/release/release-2.0.2/en_US/technical-resources.html#howtowriteconnectors)

Beside, how to go about start writing connector i would suggest you to checkout source code from manifold svn, and look at how other connectors are written. Eg. Generic connectors, File System connectors are perfect examples of how you would write connectors.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. Would you be privy to any resources on how to write a custom connector?